# angularjs ng-click not working with event

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, i am facing issue in ng-click event.I have found out that, the issue is due to click event but don't know how to rectify it.

Error thrown on clicking button:

> Error: $event is not defined

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="data in result[5]" >
    <span>
        <img ng-src={{data.image}} width="108" height="108">
    </span>
    <span>
        <input type="button" ng-click="removeProductImage($event, data.id_image)" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete this image"></input>
    </span>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.removeProductImage = function(event,photo) {
    var target = $event.target;
    var container = $(target).parent().parent();
    //container.remove();
    return $http.get("catalog-ajax.php",{params:{type:11, id_image: photo}}).then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });
};
```

Comment: What kind of error did you get? Show your console log error, or what's not working?

Comment: `var target = $event.target;`, aint that be `var target = event.target;`?

Comment: @SimoEndre Error: $event is not defined is the error shown in console

Comment: @SimoEndre my bad, thats fixed the issue, shit i spent a couple of hours in it, thanks Simo.

Comment: @veeran you shouldn't manipulate the DOM in the controller you would need to create a directive for the DOM manipulations, because it is a bad practice and you might face some data binding issues mixing Angular and jqLite or jQuery code and it would also prevent unit testing, what are you trying to achieve with the $event parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this part:

```
$scope.removeProductImage = function($event,photo) {
    var target = $event.target;
    var container = $(target).parent().parent();
    //container.remove();
    return $http.get("catalog-ajax.php",{params:{type:11, id_image: photo}}).then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });
};
```

Change it to `$event` instead of `event`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use $event instead of event**

```
 $scope.removeProductImage = function($event,photo) {
var target = $event.target;
var container = $(target).parent().parent();
//container.remove();
return $http.get("catalog-ajax.php",{params:{type:11, id_image: photo}}).then(function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter name and the variable within the methods are different. Change like this

```
$scope.removeProductImage = function($event,photo) {
    var target = $event.target;
    var container = $(target).parent().parent();
    //container.remove();
    return $http.get("catalog-ajax.php",{params:{type:11, id_image: photo}}).then(function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });
};
```